# For normal subgroups $A,B,C$ in $G$ : If $A\subseteq B$ , $A\cap C=B \cap C$ and $AC=BC$ then $A=B$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

The origin of this is question 2.54 in J Rotman - The Theory of Groups.

**Some preliminary definitions are as follows**:
Assume $N$ is a group then

1. The group operation is written multiplicatively so that $1$ is taken to be the identity of $N$ and the inverse of $a\in N$ is $a^{-1}$
2. $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$ iff for all $n\in N$: $nHn^{-1}\subseteq H$
3. If $S$ and $T$ are non-empty subsets of $N$ then $ST = \{st\in N: s\in S \ \text{and} \ t\in T\}$

**A seemingly relevant theorem goes as follows**:

*If $S,T$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ then*

- $ST=TS$
- $ST$ *is a subgroup*

**The question is then:**

> Let $A,B$ and $C$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ with $A\subseteq B$. If $A\cap C = B \cap C$ and $AC=BC$ then $A=B$

*My attempt:*
Since already $A\subseteq B$ it is enough to show that $B \subseteq A$ to conclude that $A=B$.

Let $b\in B$: If $b\in C$ then $$b\in B\cap C = A\cap C$$
so $b\in A$ which would entail that $B\subseteq A$. We therefore assume that $b \notin C$.

**Here is where I get stuck**
For $c\in C$ we have $bc\in BC$. By the "relevent" theorem above: $BC=AC=CA$. Therefore there exists a $a\in A$ and $c'\in C$ such that $bc=c'a$. Hence, since $BC=CA$ is a subgroup, $b=c'ac^{-1}\in CA$.

---

I would have liked to conclude that $c'ac^{-1}\in A$ by the fact that $A$ is normal, however I am not sure that $c=c'$. Another observation is that in $b=c'ac^{-1}$ we can not have $a\in C$ since then $b\in C$ by closure. The fact that $1b\in BC=CA$ only changes the above to $b=c'a$ but then again is $c'a\in A$

How can I proceed? a hint would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $b\in B$, we also have $b=b\cdot 1\in BC=AC$ hence we can write $b=ac$, but then $c=a^{-1}b\in B\cap C$.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $A$ is inside $B$. Take $b$ in $B$.Since $AC=BC$ $b=ac$ for some $a\in A$ and $c\in C$. Then $c$ is in $B$.  So it is in $B\cap C= A\cap C$. Hence $c$ is in $A$, so $b=ac$ is in $A$, and $B\subseteq A$. Q.E.D. This proof does not use the assumption that the subgroups are normal.